# How to write unit test case for scope and timeout function inside directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am using isolate scope in custom directive. I have updated plunker link. http://plnkr.co/edit/NBQqjxW8xvqMgfW9AVek?p=preview
Can someone help me in writing unit test case for script.js file.

script.js

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      content: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      $timeout(function() {
        element = element[0].querySelectorAll('div.outerDiv div.innerDiv3 p.myClass');
        var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
        if (height > 40) {
          angular.element(element).addClass('expandable');
          scope.isShowMore = true;
        }
      })


      scope.showMore = function() {
        angular.element(element).removeClass('expandable');
        scope.isShowMore = false;
      };

      scope.showLess = function() {
        angular.element(element).addClass('expandable');
        scope.isShowMore = true;
      };
    }
  }
})
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('Unit testing directive', function() {
    var $compile, scope, element, compiledDirective, $rootScope, $timeout;

    beforeEach(module("app"));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) {
      $compile = _$compile_;
      scope = _$rootScope_.$new();         
      $timeout = _$timeout_;
      element = angular.element(' <div my-directive content="content"></div>');
      compiledDirective = $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should apply template', function() {
      expect(compiledDirective.html()).toBe('');
    });

    it('check for timeout', function() {
      $timeout.flush();
    });

  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout.flush() function for writing testcase for $timeout

```
it('check for timeout', function() {

    scope.digest();

    // flush timeout(s) for all code under test.
    $timeout.flush();

    // this will throw an exception if there are any pending timeouts.
    $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();

    expect(scope.isShowMore).toBeTruthy();
});
```

[Check this article for better understanding.](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/11/unit-testing-code-that-uses-timeout-angularjs/)